# Generalized Tarski fixed point theorem to multivariate functions

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, lattice-orders, monotone-functions

I wish to know if a theorem like the following exists, or if there are any obvious counterexamples. This theorem generalizes Tarski's fixed point theorem in the case of powersets.

Let $X,Y$ be non-empty sets and $2^X$ the powerset of $X$.

Let $f : 2^X \times Y \to 2^X$ be such that for all $x,x' \in 2^X, y \in Y$, if $x \subseteq x'$, then $f(x,y) \subseteq f(x',y)$.

Then $f$ has at least one **fixed point**: there exists some $x \in 2^X$ such that for all $y \in Y, x = f(x,y)$.

Comment: I cannot always pick $x_0$ to be the minimum. Indeed, suppose $X$ is the powerset of some set $\overline{x}$. It could be for instance that $x_0$ is non-empty but the sequence converges to the empty set at some point. The reason I need $\mathbb{N}$ is that even though $x_t = x_{t'}$, it may not be the case that $x_{t+1} = x_{t'+1}$.

Comment: I am studying a game-theoretic model of network formation, where the network is defined over the set of players and is the product of the actions of the players (if they cooperate, a link between them is added). Different pairs of players meet at each $t \in \mathbb{N}$, thus whether a link is added depends on the players' actions and the pairing at time $t$. I want to show that a certain strategy always produces a stable graph (in equilibrium, at some point no link is added/deleted). The issue is that for any graph $g_t$, the successor $g_{t+1}$ depends on the pairing at $t+1$.

Comment: Letting $G$ be the powerset of the complete graph over the players, and fixing a strategy profile, I'd like to define a successor function $f : G \times \mathbb{N}  \to G$ which takes a graph $g_{t}$, the set of players who meet at time $t+1$, and yields the resulting graph $g_{t+1} =: f(g_{t}, t+1)$.

Comment: I have a strategy profile defined. Said strategy profile satisfies $\subseteq$-monotonicity in the sense that if two networks $g, g'$ are such that $g \subseteq g'$, and two players cooperate when the network is $g$, then they cooperate when the network is $g'$. Do you need the details of the strategy profile to know whether a Tarski-like theorem exists?

Comment: Counterexample: $X=Y=\{0,1\}$, and $f(x,y) = \{y\}$.

Comment: aschepler's counter-example is sufficient to disprove your concept. More generally, $Y$ serves no purpose in this other than to act as a index of increasing (with respect to $\subseteq$) functions $2^X \to 2^X$, so effectively you are saying all such increasing functions must have *the same* fixed point.